# OHS + weblogic - Customize error 500

Tags: apache-2.2, errordocument, weblogic

and sorry if the question looks stupid (it may be ^^), I'm a newbie in HTTP server.

We use OBIEE 11g, that means we have Weblogic and we chose to use an Oracle HTTP Server (OHS, built on Apache) in front. OHS uses `mod_wl_ohs` to interact with Weblogic, here is the `mod_wl_ohs.conf` file:

```
## Fusion Applications Name Based Virtual Host Configuration

RedirectMatch 301 ^/analytics$ /analytics/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/AdminService$ /AdminService/

LoadModule weblogic_module   "${ORACLE_HOME}/ohs/modules/mod_wl_ohs.so"

# global plugin-options
WLForwardUriUnparsed ON
KeepAliveEnabled ON
KeepAliveSecs 20
DynamicServerList OFF
WLProxySSL ON

## Context roots for BI EE
<Location /analytics >
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
 WebLogicCluster miaibv194.mia.michelin.com:9704
</Location>
## Context roots for AdminService
<Location /AdminService >
 SetHandler weblogic-handler
 WebLogicCluster miaibv194.mia.michelin.com:7001
</Location>
```

If I understand well, the RedirectMatch and corresponding Location directives (even if I don't get exactly the responsibilities of the 2) are used to pass URLs like `/analytics` and `/AdminService` to Weblogic.

I'd like to know how I could redirect HTTP errors 500 from URLs like `/analytics` to a custom page: is this possible ? I had a look at the `ErrorDocument` directive, but from what I could see it appeared it could only be used for physical path (i.e. under the `Directory` directive for instance), did I miss something ?

Thanks for your help, and do not hesitate to ask me for clarifications (I'll try to answer the best as I can) !

Comment: See answer on [same subject opened on Stack Overflow][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525534/can-custom-http-error-500-be-specified-under-location-directive/12635587#12635587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I was originally trying to achieve was to customize HTTP errors 500 in OBIEE 11g (which uses WebLogic, and an OHS in our case). I opened a SR to try to achieve that with OHS, but it failed (Oracle guy told me I had to do it at application level), so I opened a new one to do it with WebLogic itself and here is what it gives:

• Locate the analytics.ear in your Oracle BI Home directory. This will be /Oracle_BI1 (or whatever you chose to name your Oracle BI Home on install)/bifoundation/analytics.ear. So in our example scenario, this would be located at: C:\OBI\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\jee\analytics.ear • Make a backup copy of the ear file so that you have a restore point to refer back to (and revert to) if needed Note that we do not support updating the analytics.ear file, you must stop, remove the previous analytics.ear file before deploying the new one.

• Unpack the analytics.ear file to a temporary location, using the Java jar tool. Use the command line options xvf to extract the contents to the current working directory (e.g. C:\OBI\jdk160\bin\jar –xvf C:\OBI\Oracle_BI1\bifoundation\jee\analytics.ear), so you will probably want to create a temporary directory to hold the unpacked contents and change into that directory before running the command.

The ear contains a META-INF directory and two war files, analytics.war and analytics-ws.war

• In the META-INF directory, there is a MANIFEST.MF file, add the following line to the end of the file: Weblogic-Application-Version: 11.1.1 Note that it has been reported that when re-applying these steps following the application of BI 11.1.1.5.0 BP2 patches, this step to update MANIFEST.MF should be ignored as the new analytics.ear file is not versioned.

• Unpack the analytics.war file to a second temporary location; it contains a default.jsp file and five top-level directories, one of which is called WEB-INF.

• in the WEB-INF directory, you will find an existing file called web.xml. Edit web.xml, for example by adding:

```
<error-page>
<error-code>500</error-code>
<location>/500error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Make sure there are no hidden characters and check the quotes are correct for your platform.

• Once you have edited the web.xml , repackage the analytics.war file, again using the jar tool, and, in turn, repackage that back into the analytics.ear file. Next we need to redeploy the analytics.ear file to Weblogic

• Log into Weblogic Admin Console and click on Deployments

• In the Change Centre at the top left, click “Lock and Edit”

• Find the analytics app and click the tickbox next to it, then click on the Update button

• In the Update Application Assistant screen, make sure the deployment path is the same as the ear file you just updated, if not change the path

• Click Next, then Finish

• In the Change Centre at the top left, click “Activate Changes” to save your changes. If you have not already done so, restart the Weblogic Admin Server and all Managed Servers